# Javascript instance variable didn't get rendered in React class component when calling setState

Tags: javascript, reactjs

A react class component is mounted to html root node. It has two react element `h1` tag in its body.  One `h1` element is directly render inside the render method. Another `h1` is decleared in React component class and passed into Render function as a variable.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

export default class Test extends Component {
  state = {
    count: 0,
  };

  current_count = (<h1>current count is {this.state.count}</h1>);

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        {this.current_count}
        <h1>current count is {this.state.count}</h1>
        <button
          onClick={() => {
            this.setState({ count: this.state.count + 1 });
          }}
        >
          click me
        </button>
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

When I clicked the button, it should increase the `count`, only the react element `h1` inside the render function will updated with it's state content.

The following photo is shown the second `h1` tag showing count is 4 when I clicked the button 4 times.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Your `current_count` is a property that gets created in the constructor, before mount, and only then. Your current code is like

```
export default class Test extends Component {
  constructor() {
    this.state = {
      count: 0,
    };
    this.current_count = (<h1>current count is {this.state.count}</h1>);
  }
```

And the constructor only runs once.

You'll need some other method to update it. The best way would be to only generate the JSX on render - perhaps have a function instead that returns the `<h1>`.

```js
class Test extends React.Component {
  state = {
    count: 0,
  };

  getCurrentCount() {
    return (
      <h1>current count is {this.state.count}</h1>
    );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        {this.getCurrentCount()}
        <h1>current count is {this.state.count}</h1>
        <button
          onClick={() => {
            this.setState({ count: this.state.count + 1 });
          }}
        >
          click me
        </button>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.querySelector('.react')).render(<Test />);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div class='react'></div>
```